# Getting two button clicks when I use a hidden-xs button with bootstrap (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, click

Example here:

https://embed.plnkr.co/TGPRooggnDNO4FEiWmXb/

Here is the bootstrap HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default hidden-xs" (click)="voteUp()" style="margin-top:5px; margin-right:5px; margin-left: 5px;">Vote up&nbsp;
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" [@upArrowState]="upArrowState" (@upArrowState.done)="upArrowAnimationDone($event, post, true)"></span>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default visible-xs btn-vote" (click)="voteUp()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" style="left: -2px" [@upArrowState]="upArrowState" (@upArrowState.done)="upArrowAnimationDone($event, post, true)"></span>
</button>
```

So I assume the hidden-xs button and the visible-xs button are both at the same place at all times and both register the (click) event. Even the button that are invisible.

I only want one click (or just the visible button to register a button click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click handler is called just once, you can see that if you move the `console.log` to the `voteUp()` handler. This problem is connected to the animations.

I think you should definitely move the logic (`this.vote()` call) there, not to the animation callback.

Other possibility would probably be to use the `(@upArrowState.done)="upArrowAnimationDone($event, post, true)"` just once, not on both buttons.

The problem is better visible when you remove those `hidden/visible` classes - as the animation has same name, you will see that clicking one button will toggle the animation on both of them, resulting in calling the animation callback for each of them.